# Receiving an EventArc trigger for a specific GCS bucket only

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-run, event-arc

I'm trying to setup an EventArc trigger on a google cloud run project, to be run whenever a new file is uploaded to a particular bucket.

The problem is, I can only get it to work if I choose `any resource`, i.e files uploaded to any of my buckets would run the trigger. However, I only want it to run for files uploaded to a specific bucket.

It asks me to enter the 'full resource name' if I choose 'a specific resource'. But there seems to be no documentation on how to format the bucket name so that it will work. I've tried the bucket name, `projects/_/buckets/my_bucket_name`, but the trigger never runs unless I choose 'any resource'.

Any ideas how to give it the bucket name so this will work?

Comment: I think the answer may be buried in here .... https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/demystifying-event-filters-eventarc

If we read it deeply, we seem to see that event origination is based on audit records being created.  We see that a record is created when a new object is created in your bucket.  We then read that we can filter on resource name (the name of the object).  However it says that wildcards are not yet supported ... so you could trigger on a specific object name ... but not a name which is prefixed by your bucket name.

Comment: feel free to post that as an answer @Kolban

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the answer may be buried in here .... [cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/demystifying-event-filters-eventarc)… If we read it deeply, we seem to see that event origination is based on audit records being created. We see that a record is created when a new object is created in your bucket. We then read that we can filter on resource name (the name of the object). However it says that wildcards are not yet supported ... so you could trigger on a specific object name ... but not a name which is prefixed by your bucket name.

Answer (score 0):

Eventarc now supports wildcards (path pattern) for cloud audit log based events (e.g., storage.objects.create)

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WaPS.png)